# Proof of Path-independence of work done by an electrostatic field using Coulomb's law

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, coulombs-law, conservative-field

We know that work done by conservative forces is path-independent but how can we prove it using Coulomb's law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know from Coulombs law that the electric field a distance $r$ from a point charge is given by
$$
\mathbf{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}} \tag{1}
$$
To show that work done by an electrostatic field is path independent, we will invoke Stoke's theorem to transform a surface integral into a path integral.
$$
\int_S(\nabla\times\mathbf{E})\cdot d\mathbf{S} =
\oint_P \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}\tag{3}
$$
If we can thus show that 
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=0\tag{2}
$$
it will follows from eq. $(3)$ that the the electric field is path independent.

The gradient/ dell operator in spherical coordinates is written as
$$
\nabla = \hat{\mathbf{r}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
+\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}
+\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\tag{4}
$$
I leave it to you now as an easy exercise to now show that $\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=0$